# Showing that a ring is Abelian algebraic ring with multiplication "$\cap$" and addition "$\Delta$"

Tags: probability-theory

The question is the following:
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a ring on the set $\Omega$. Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is an Abelian algebraic ring with multiplication "$\cap$" and addition "$\Delta$".

So I looked up what it means to be an Abelian group: (It is a set A, together with an operation $\cdot$ that satisfies the requirements listed below)

1) Closure: $a \cdot b \in A$ for $a,b \in A$

2) Associativity: $(a \cdot b)\cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)$ for $a,b,c \in A$

3) Identity element: $\exists e \in A$ s.t. $e \cdot a = a \cdot e = a$ for $a \in A$

4) Inverse element: $\exists b \in A$ s.t. $b \cdot a = a \cdot b = e$ for $a \in A$

5) Commutativity: $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$ for $a,b \in A$

And Abelian algebraic ring I found is just some set A with two operations instead of one (that generalize binary addition and multiplication). **So I thought that each operation has to satisfy the above 5 requirements! And I think this may be my thinking fallacy!**

And here are ring requirements for your convenience: a class of sets $\mathcal{A} \subset 2^{\Omega}$ is called a ring if it satisfies: (i) $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$; (ii) \-closed (i.e. difference closed); (iii) $\cup$-closed;

When I started proving separately starting with $\cap$ that it satisfies the above requirements I got stuck on 3). I initially thought that it must be the $\Omega$, because whatever you intersect with it, gives you back that other element. But two problems with this, first of all, it is not in the ring (at least I could not show it) and two, it is too large, i.e. such element $b$ in 5) does not simply exist when you intersect on it gives you back $\Omega$...

Comment: Probably the problem is asking you to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a commutative ring. The issue is that, with your definition of ring, it may lack a multiplicative identity. (Old school may consider rings without multiplicative identity, but as far as I heard it is not a common practice in modern literature to the point that people jokingly call such things **rng** because they lack **i**dentity.)  For instance, consider the family $\mathcal{A}$ of all finite subsets of some infinite set $\Omega$.

Comment: Look at the [definition of Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) It's not true that both the operations (usually called *addition* and *multiplication*) will satisfy all the properties that you wrote.